# JQuery jTable set parameters on table cells

Tags: jquery, jquery-jtable

Is it possible to set parameters on jTable's table cells, something like this?

```
<td data-iuser_key=9499949 data-cuser_lnm='testing' class=userdata>

</td>
```

I know how to set params on inner elements, but I don't know how to set params on table cells. For inner elements, something like this:

```
input: function (data) {
        if (data.record) {
            return '<input type="text" name="Name" style="width:200px" value="' + data.record.Name + '" />';
        } else {
            return '<input type="text" name="Name" style="width:200px" value="enter your name here" />';
        }
```

My code:

```
$('#tblOffers').jtable({
    title: 'Offers',
    paging: true,
    pageSize: 20,
    sorting: true,
    defaultSorting: 'cORAC_NUM DESC',
    actions: {
      listAction: "/SalesOfferInvoiceDeliveryNote/SearchOffers/"
    },        
    fields: {
      cORAC_NUM: {
        key: true,        
        title: 'ORAC number'
      },
      cORAC_DAT: {
        title: 'Date'
      },
      cACCO_NME: {
        title: 'Customer'
      },
      ORAC_GRO_SUM: {
        title: 'Paying'
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: i don't think so.  i tag the inner cell like you do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code shows a field input function not a field display function. The input function is used inside create/edit forms and never appears in the table itself, for that you must use a display function. Your problem arises because when display function is created, the `td` that you wish to manipulate does not yet exist in the DOM.

In addition to the display function, there is also the field option listClass which will add the class to the containing `td`.

You can of course use the display function, to create a `div` wrapper around you display content, and you can add 'parameters' to the `div`.

Such that a field definition like

```
rockBand: {
   listClass: 'rockNroll',
   display: function (data) {
       var div = $('<div />')
                  .attr('data-iuser_key',9499949)
                  .attr('data-cuser_lnm','testing');
       div.append(data.record.rockBand);
       return div;
   }
```

}

should generate a DOM like

```
<td class='rockNroll'>
    <div data-iuser_key=9499949 data-cuser_lnm='testing'>
        The rolling Stones
    </div>
</td>
```

I would have thought it would be easy enough to structure jQuery selectors to find the `td.rockNroll > div` combinations as readily as `td`. You have not explained why you need to add parameters to the 'td' itself. If you absolutely must have the 'parameters' on the `td` element itself, you could always use the jTable `recordsLoaded` event, to go back over the table just constructed, and promote the parameters sitting on the `div` element to the parent `td` element.